# How to pass parameter for selected value of Combobox and get values for the parameter from database

Tags: extjs

I am using ext js.
I have combo box where I am selecting a value and using this value as parameter to get other values (two values). Now I want this to be added to a variable so I can use it in other places other than the combobox. How can I do this?

```
var txtEP=new Ext.form.ComboBox({
           renderTo: "txtEP",
           fieldLabel: 'End Point',
           triggerAction: "all",
           forceSelection: true,
           mode:'local',
           autoScroll: true,
           allowBlank: false,
           autoShow: true,
           typeAhead:true,
           store: genres,
           valueField:'pincode',
           displayField:'pincode',
           emptyText:'Select a Start Point',
           selectOnFocus:true,
           listeners : {
               'select' : function(){
               var selVal = this.getValue();
            //endpt(Global Variable) is the variable where i am trying to get this value.
            endpt=store.load({url:'./genres1.php', params: {pincode: selVal}});
                   alert(endpt);
                   }
               }
           //valueField: 'X,Y'     
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to assign it in a callback as a config of `store.load` this is because when you assign it right away the store does not contain any data. Something like this:

```
var txtEP = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    renderTo: "txtEP",
    fieldLabel: 'End Point',
    triggerAction: "all",
    forceSelection: true,
    mode:'local',
    autoScroll: true,
    allowBlank: false,
    autoShow: true,
    typeAhead:true,
    store: genres,
    valueField:'pincode',
    displayField:'pincode',
    emptyText:'Select a Start Point',
    selectOnFocus:true,
    listeners : {
        'select' : function(){
            var selVal = this.getValue();
            store.load({
                url:'./genres1.php', 
                params: {pincode: selVal},
                callback: function(records) {
                    endpt = records; // here is where it is assigned
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Realize also, that "endpt" will now contain an array of Ext.data.Model objects so you can use the methods given [**here**](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Model) to extract whatever values you need from them.

**To answer your comment:**

Ext.data.Model has a `get` method. You pass it the name of the field you want to get values with. In your case, you mentioned somewhere that `/genres.php` returns two values, if the data is returned as one record with two different columns like this:

column header: | value1 | value2

row 1: | 'data1' | 'data2'

You could assign the two returned data values to variables in your callback function like this, say you named your variables `firstValue` and `secondValue`:

```
firstValue = endpt[0].get('value1');
secondValue = endpt[0].get('value2');
```

If instead, your `/genres.php` returns the data as two different rows with only one column header like this:

column header: value

row 1: 'data1'

row 2: 'data2'

You could assign the data to variables like this:

```
firstValue = endpt[0].get('value');
secondValue = endpt[1].get('value');
```

Comment: First Thanks. But how would I now Use array of Ext.data.Model object please help as new to this.

Comment: @user1220259 I added examples of how to go about this

Comment: @user1220259 don't forget to accept the answer if this works out for you (checkmark on the left)